# Dismiss a Modal-Presented UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

EDIT: Added code that contains the dismissal.

**NEW DATA**

The problem remains the same as the problem listed under old data, except the dismissal line has changed.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Calling Dismissal...");
        [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

The function is being called because "Calling Dismissal..." is displayed in the log.

Current Hierarchy: UITabBarController - NavigationController/NavigationController - View1/View2

**OLD DATA**

In case the question was confusing, I am trying to dismiss a UITabBarController than I presented modally.  The UITabBarController does use NavigationControllers to setup the two views inside.  However, no matter how many parentViewController s I put in

(i.e.):

```
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController.etc... dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

The UITableBarController will not dismiss.  I have a button being placed in the NavigationController of both views that is calling the line of code above.  Any hints on how to dismiss the UITableViewController?

Answer (score 0):

The presenting view controller, which is not the same concept as the parent view controller, needs to dismiss it.  This code:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

will typically do the trick.

However, depending on what this controller's function is, I usually prefer to have my presented controllers send a delegate message or `NSNotification` to the parent, so the parent can extract whatever data it needs before dismissal.

Comment: Yea I had that in the code before the parentViewContoller, and it still wouldn't dismiss the view.  I put it back in just now to test it again and still no luck.  The button is calling the function though, the view just will not dismiss

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and then in the console type `po self` and `po self.presentingViewController`.  If "self" is the tab bar controller and "self.presentingViewController" is `nil` then you are not presenting the tab bar controller from another view controller, and therefore cannot dismiss it.  (View controllers can only be dismissed if they are presented.)

Comment: I apologize for the extremely delayed response, I'm in the middle of exams.  I typed in `po self` and `po self.presentingViewController`.  `po self` came up as `(PitView *) $2 = 0x08c532b0 <PitView: 0x8c532b0>`, which is a UIViewController.  `po self.presentingViewController` came up with `(UIViewController *) $3 = 0x00000000 <nil>` which I assume isn't what should be coming up.